# how to generate HAR file in the Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, har

I want to use the function 'Preserve log' at the network tab in the Chrome Dev Tools. I searched internet and found following site. However, it does not work as it indicates. Does anyone have used preserve log and generate HAR file from it? Actually, I am wondering about the exact function of 'preserve log' itself.. Is is for generating HAR file?

https://community.box.com/t5/Managing-Content-Troubleshooting/How-to-Generate-a-HAR-File-in-Chrome-IE-or-Firefox/ta-p/366

Could you please help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

"Preserve log: option this is not the same like saving HAR file. You need preserve log in order to see the log even you refresh the page or move to another page. However you can't save full HAR file if this check box unchecked. So "preserve log" is required for HAR but it has other meaning.

Answer (score 0):

*** Disclaimer: Posted by Developer of HttpWatch ***

[HttpWatch](https://www.httpwatch.com) on Windows can record the network traffic generated when a new Chrome tab or window is opened by enabling auto-recording in Tools->Options->Recording. In the new window click on the HttpWatch icon to view the network trace.The log file can either be saved a HAR or in the native HttpWatch format (HWL)

The [free version](https://www.httpwatch.com/download/) will record a full HWL file that can be opened by someone using HttpWatch Professional.

*** Disclaimer: Posted by Developer of HttpWatch ***